# Google Mini License

Tags: google-search-appliance

I have a Google Mini appliance with the 50,000 document license. Does anyone know what happens when my document count goes over 50,000? The mini is still working and obviously, the true 2 year license does not apply anymore but will it start to falter over the document limit? Thanks.

Comment: This site is for asking programming related questions.  This question would be more appropriate to either then SuperUser or ServerFault sites.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Mini is no longer supported by Google so if you run into any issues then you will not have tech support to resolve the issue. Most Google Mini users have migrated to other options.